# Jade template does not seem to be getting data from Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

In the get handler, I create an object, `plans`, from my data source. Then I do:

```
console.log(plans);
res.render('dashboard', plans);
```

It prints:

```
{ '0': 'mobile_basic',
  '1': 'mobile_basic',
  '2': 'landline_basic',
  '3': 'landline_mid',
  '4': 'internet_mid' }
```

This means that this object is being passed into the template. In the `dashboard` Jade template, I have:

```
if plans
  ul
    each val, index in plans
      li= index + ': ' + val
```

This never shows up. `plans` is undefined in the template's context. What am I missing?

P.S. I have tried using `res.render('dashboard', {data: plans});` and replacing `plans` in the template with `data.plans`. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the variable holding your data doesn't actually get passed along through `res.render()` to the view engine. Only its value does.

What the view can use are the keys/properties specified within the `locals`:

```
res.render('dashboard', { plans: plans });
//                        ^^^^^
```

These keys will become the local variables within the view.

---

When you attempted to use:

```
res.render('dashboard', { data: plans });
```

The view could have in turn used `data` to access the collection from `plans`:

```
if data # <--
  ul
    each val, index in data # <--
      li= index + ': ' + val
```

Comment: I did try that before, but I probably had something off. It ended up working when I tried again. Also, I didn't know that the name of the object does not get passed in. Thanks!